# Suitable safe cleaning solution for aliphatic urethane

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solutions, solvents, cleaning

I am looking for a suitable cleaning solution for a sprayed on coating that is an acrylic aliphatic urethane. My end goal would ideally be something that can neutralize rust, whiten and brighten the surface, and also include a powerful enough solvent that can loosen stuck on dirt/soap scum but not harm the urethane.

The urethane is approximately 70% solids (don't know if that matters or not). I'm not a chemist so layman's terms would help greatly.

Comment: There may be specific solutions designed to work with that sort of surface, but a good solvent to try if you can't find any information on them would be isopropanol which tends not to destroy plastics and is good at removing grease and contamination from surfaces. As always, try on a small area first in case there is some interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Oxalic acid is good at removing rust (iron oxides) and generally not agressive against polymers like polyurethanes.
Chemical resistance of polymers is however a complicated area, because polymers comes in a wide spectrum of formulations, additives etc. Some indications can be found on different manufacturers websides